# How to chop the corners/ edges from CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to chop/cut the corners/edges from the CSS. As I'm able to slant the horizontal bar.
But not able to cut the corners `br-theme-bars-1to10` from the CSS as shown in the expected result.

```js
$(function() {
  function ratingEnable() {
    $('#example-1to10').barrating('show', {
      theme: 'bars-1to10'
    });
  }

  function ratingDisable() {
    $('select').barrating('destroy');
  }

  $('.rating-enable').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    ratingEnable();

    $(this).addClass('deactivated');
    $('.rating-disable').removeClass('deactivated');
  });

  $('.rating-disable').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    ratingDisable();

    $(this).addClass('deactivated');
    $('.rating-enable').removeClass('deactivated');
  });

  ratingEnable();
});

! function(t) {
  "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], t) : "object" == typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = t(require("jquery")) : t(jQuery)
}(function(t) {
  var e = function() {
    function e() {
      var e = this,
        n = function() {
          var n = ["br-wrapper"];
          "" !== e.options.theme && n.push("br-theme-" + e.options.theme), e.$elem.wrap(t("<div />", {
            "class": n.join(" ")
          }))
        },
        i = function() {
          e.$elem.unwrap()
        },
        a = function(n) {
          return t.isNumeric(n) && (n = Math.floor(n)), t('option[value="' + n + '"]', e.$elem)
        },
        r = function() {
          var n = e.options.initialRating;
          return n ? a(n) : t("option:selected", e.$elem)
        },
        o = function() {
          var n = e.$elem.find('option[value="' + e.options.emptyValue + '"]');
          return !n.length && e.options.allowEmpty ? (n = t("<option />", {
            value: e.options.emptyValue
          }), n.prependTo(e.$elem)) : n
        },
        l = function(t) {
          var n = e.$elem.data("barrating");
          return "undefined" != typeof t ? n[t] : n
        },
        s = function(t, n) {
          null !== n && "object" == typeof n ? e.$elem.data("barrating", n) : e.$elem.data("barrating")[t] = n
        },
        u = function() {
          var t = r(),
            n = o(),
            i = t.val(),
            a = t.data("html") ? t.data("html") : t.text(),
            l = null !== e.options.allowEmpty ? e.options.allowEmpty : !!n.length,
            u = n.length ? n.val() : null,
            d = n.length ? n.text() : null;
          s(null, {
            userOptions: e.options,
            ratingValue: i,
            ratingText: a,
            originalRatingValue: i,
            originalRatingText: a,
            allowEmpty: l,
            emptyRatingValue: u,
            emptyRatingText: d,
            readOnly: e.options.readonly,
            ratingMade: !1
          })
        },
        d = function() {
          e.$elem.removeData("barrating")
        },
        c = function() {
          return l("ratingText")
        },
        f = function() {
          return l("ratingValue")
        },
        g = function() {
          var n = t("<div />", {
            "class": "br-widget"
          });
          return e.$elem.find("option").each(function() {
            var i, a, r, o;
            i = t(this).val(), i !== l("emptyRatingValue") && (a = t(this).text(), r = t(this).data("html"), r && (a = r), o = t("<a />", {
              href: "#",
              "data-rating-value": i,
              "data-rating-text": a,
              html: e.options.showValues ? a : ""
            }), n.append(o))
          }), e.options.showSelectedRating && n.append(t("<div />", {
            text: "",
            "class": "br-current-rating"
          })), e.options.reverse && n.addClass("br-reverse"), e.options.readonly && n.addClass("br-readonly"), n
        },
        p = function() {
          return l("userOptions").reverse ? "nextAll" : "prevAll"
        },
        h = function(t) {
          a(t).prop("selected", !0), l("userOptions").triggerChange && e.$elem.change()
        },
        m = function() {
          t("option", e.$elem).prop("selected", function() {
            return this.defaultSelected
          }), l("userOptions").triggerChange && e.$elem.change()
        },
        v = function(t) {
          t = t ? t : c(), t == l("emptyRatingText") && (t = ""), e.options.showSelectedRating && e.$elem.parent().find(".br-current-rating").text(t)
        },
        y = function(t) {
          return Math.round(Math.floor(10 * t) / 10 % 1 * 100)
        },
        b = function() {
          e.$widget.find("a").removeClass(function(t, e) {
            return (e.match(/(^|\s)br-\S+/g) || []).join(" ")
          })
        },
        w = function() {
          var n, i, a = e.$widget.find('a[data-rating-value="' + f() + '"]'),
            r = l("userOptions").initialRating,
            o = t.isNumeric(f()) ? f() : 0,
            s = y(r);
          if (b(), a.addClass("br-selected br-current")[p()]().addClass("br-selected"), !l("ratingMade") && t.isNumeric(r)) {
            if (o >= r || !s) return;
            n = e.$widget.find("a"), i = a.length ? a[l("userOptions").reverse ? "prev" : "next"]() : n[l("userOptions").reverse ? "last" : "first"](), i.addClass("br-fractional"), i.addClass("br-fractional-" + s)
          }
        },
        $ = function(t) {
          return l("allowEmpty") && l("userOptions").deselectable ? f() == t.attr("data-rating-value") : !1
        },
        x = function(n) {
          n.on("click.barrating", function(n) {
            var i, a, r = t(this),
              o = l("userOptions");
            return n.preventDefault(), i = r.attr("data-rating-value"), a = r.attr("data-rating-text"), $(r) && (i = l("emptyRatingValue"), a = l("emptyRatingText")), s("ratingValue", i), s("ratingText", a), s("ratingMade", !0), h(i), v(a), w(), o.onSelect.call(e, f(), c(), n), !1
          })
        },
        C = function(e) {
          e.on("mouseenter.barrating", function() {
            var e = t(this);
            b(), e.addClass("br-active")[p()]().addClass("br-active"), v(e.attr("data-rating-text"))
          })
        },
        O = function(t) {
          e.$widget.on("mouseleave.barrating blur.barrating", function() {
            v(), w()
          })
        },
        R = function(e) {
          e.on("touchstart.barrating", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation(), t(this).click()
          })
        },
        V = function(t) {
          t.on("click.barrating", function(t) {
            t.preventDefault()
          })
        },
        S = function(t) {
          x(t), e.options.hoverState && (C(t), O(t))
        },
        T = function(t) {
          t.off(".barrating")
        },
        j = function(t) {
          var n = e.$widget.find("a");
          l("userOptions").fastClicks && R(n), t ? (T(n), V(n)) : S(n)
        };
      this.show = function() {
        l() || (n(), u(), e.$widget = g(), e.$widget.insertAfter(e.$elem), w(), v(), j(e.options.readonly), e.$elem.hide())
      }, this.readonly = function(t) {
        "boolean" == typeof t && l("readOnly") != t && (j(t), s("readOnly", t), e.$widget.toggleClass("br-readonly"))
      }, this.set = function(t) {
        var n = l("userOptions");
        0 !== e.$elem.find('option[value="' + t + '"]').length && (s("ratingValue", t), s("ratingText", e.$elem.find('option[value="' + t + '"]').text()), s("ratingMade", !0), h(f()), v(c()), w(), n.silent || n.onSelect.call(this, f(), c()))
      }, this.clear = function() {
        var t = l("userOptions");
        s("ratingValue", l("originalRatingValue")), s("ratingText", l("originalRatingText")), s("ratingMade", !1), m(), v(c()), w(), t.onClear.call(this, f(), c())
      }, this.destroy = function() {
        var t = f(),
          n = c(),
          a = l("userOptions");
        T(e.$widget.find("a")), e.$widget.remove(), d(), i(), e.$elem.show(), a.onDestroy.call(this, t, n)
      }
    }
    return e.prototype.init = function(e, n) {
      return this.$elem = t(n), this.options = t.extend({}, t.fn.barrating.defaults, e), this.options
    }, e
  }();
  t.fn.barrating = function(n, i) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var a = new e;
      if (t(this).is("select") || t.error("Sorry, this plugin only works with select fields."), a.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
        if (a.init(i, this), "show" === n) return a.show(i);
        if (a.$elem.data("barrating")) return a.$widget = t(this).next(".br-widget"), a[n](i)
      } else {
        if ("object" == typeof n || !n) return i = n, a.init(i, this), a.show();
        t.error("Method " + n + " does not exist on jQuery.barrating")
      }
    })
  }, t.fn.barrating.defaults = {
    theme: "",
    initialRating: null,
    allowEmpty: null,
    emptyValue: "",
    showValues: !1,
    showSelectedRating: !0,
    deselectable: !0,
    reverse: !1,
    readonly: !1,
    fastClicks: !0,
    hoverState: !0,
    silent: !1,
    triggerChange: !0,
    onSelect: function(t, e, n) {},
    onClear: function(t, e) {},
    onDestroy: function(t, e) {}
  }, t.fn.barrating.BarRating = e
});
//# sourceMappingURL=jquery.barrating.min.js.map
```

```css
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget {
  height: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fbedd9;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(29deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(29deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(29deg);
}
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-active,
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-selected {
  /* background-color: #EDB867; */
  background-image: linear-gradient( #49b4ff,  #043063);
}
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget .br-current-rating {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 2;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  color: #EDB867; /* number color */
  font-weight: 400;
}
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-readonly a {
  cursor: default;
}
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-readonly a.br-active,
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-readonly a.br-selected {
  /* background-color: #f2cd95; */
  background-image: linear-gradient( #49b4ff,  #043063);
}
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-readonly .br-current-rating {
  /* color: #f2cd95; */
  background-image: linear-gradient( #49b4ff,  #043063);
}
@media print {
  .br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a {
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    background: white;
    height: 38px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-active,
  .br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-selected {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
  }
  .br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget .br-current-rating {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/jquery.barrating.js"></script>
<link href="http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/dist/themes/fontawesome-stars.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <script>window.html5 || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/html5shiv.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <section class="">
    <select id="example-1to10" name="rating" autocomplete="off">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7" selected="selected">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

  </section>



  <script src="https://github.com/antennaio/jquery-bar-rating/blob/master/dist/jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script> -->

</body>

</html>
```

**Actual Result:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

Comment: you should `skew` not `rotate`

Comment: `skew(-31deg, 0deg);` that did the trick @TemaniAfif Thanks

Comment: no need the second argument, skew(-31deg) should be enough

Comment: Yes your right @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 1):

try using `Skew` property. check snippet.

```
-moz-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
-webkit-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
-o-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
-ms-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
```

```js
$(function() {
  function ratingEnable() {
    $('#example-1to10').barrating('show', {
      theme: 'bars-1to10'
    });
  }

  function ratingDisable() {
    $('select').barrating('destroy');
  }

  $('.rating-enable').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    ratingEnable();

    $(this).addClass('deactivated');
    $('.rating-disable').removeClass('deactivated');
  });

  $('.rating-disable').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    ratingDisable();

    $(this).addClass('deactivated');
    $('.rating-enable').removeClass('deactivated');
  });

  ratingEnable();
});

! function(t) {
  "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], t) : "object" == typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = t(require("jquery")) : t(jQuery)
}(function(t) {
  var e = function() {
    function e() {
      var e = this,
        n = function() {
          var n = ["br-wrapper"];
          "" !== e.options.theme && n.push("br-theme-" + e.options.theme), e.$elem.wrap(t("<div />", {
            "class": n.join(" ")
          }))
        },
        i = function() {
          e.$elem.unwrap()
        },
        a = function(n) {
          return t.isNumeric(n) && (n = Math.floor(n)), t('option[value="' + n + '"]', e.$elem)
        },
        r = function() {
          var n = e.options.initialRating;
          return n ? a(n) : t("option:selected", e.$elem)
        },
        o = function() {
          var n = e.$elem.find('option[value="' + e.options.emptyValue + '"]');
          return !n.length && e.options.allowEmpty ? (n = t("<option />", {
            value: e.options.emptyValue
          }), n.prependTo(e.$elem)) : n
        },
        l = function(t) {
          var n = e.$elem.data("barrating");
          return "undefined" != typeof t ? n[t] : n
        },
        s = function(t, n) {
          null !== n && "object" == typeof n ? e.$elem.data("barrating", n) : e.$elem.data("barrating")[t] = n
        },
        u = function() {
          var t = r(),
            n = o(),
            i = t.val(),
            a = t.data("html") ? t.data("html") : t.text(),
            l = null !== e.options.allowEmpty ? e.options.allowEmpty : !!n.length,
            u = n.length ? n.val() : null,
            d = n.length ? n.text() : null;
          s(null, {
            userOptions: e.options,
            ratingValue: i,
            ratingText: a,
            originalRatingValue: i,
            originalRatingText: a,
            allowEmpty: l,
            emptyRatingValue: u,
            emptyRatingText: d,
            readOnly: e.options.readonly,
            ratingMade: !1
          })
        },
        d = function() {
          e.$elem.removeData("barrating")
        },
        c = function() {
          return l("ratingText")
        },
        f = function() {
          return l("ratingValue")
        },
        g = function() {
          var n = t("<div />", {
            "class": "br-widget"
          });
          return e.$elem.find("option").each(function() {
            var i, a, r, o;
            i = t(this).val(), i !== l("emptyRatingValue") && (a = t(this).text(), r = t(this).data("html"), r && (a = r), o = t("<a />", {
              href: "#",
              "data-rating-value": i,
              "data-rating-text": a,
              html: e.options.showValues ? a : ""
            }), n.append(o))
          }), e.options.showSelectedRating && n.append(t("<div />", {
            text: "",
            "class": "br-current-rating"
          })), e.options.reverse && n.addClass("br-reverse"), e.options.readonly && n.addClass("br-readonly"), n
        },
        p = function() {
          return l("userOptions").reverse ? "nextAll" : "prevAll"
        },
        h = function(t) {
          a(t).prop("selected", !0), l("userOptions").triggerChange && e.$elem.change()
        },
        m = function() {
          t("option", e.$elem).prop("selected", function() {
            return this.defaultSelected
          }), l("userOptions").triggerChange && e.$elem.change()
        },
        v = function(t) {
          t = t ? t : c(), t == l("emptyRatingText") && (t = ""), e.options.showSelectedRating && e.$elem.parent().find(".br-current-rating").text(t)
        },
        y = function(t) {
          return Math.round(Math.floor(10 * t) / 10 % 1 * 100)
        },
        b = function() {
          e.$widget.find("a").removeClass(function(t, e) {
            return (e.match(/(^|\s)br-\S+/g) || []).join(" ")
          })
        },
        w = function() {
          var n, i, a = e.$widget.find('a[data-rating-value="' + f() + '"]'),
            r = l("userOptions").initialRating,
            o = t.isNumeric(f()) ? f() : 0,
            s = y(r);
          if (b(), a.addClass("br-selected br-current")[p()]().addClass("br-selected"), !l("ratingMade") && t.isNumeric(r)) {
            if (o >= r || !s) return;
            n = e.$widget.find("a"), i = a.length ? a[l("userOptions").reverse ? "prev" : "next"]() : n[l("userOptions").reverse ? "last" : "first"](), i.addClass("br-fractional"), i.addClass("br-fractional-" + s)
          }
        },
        $ = function(t) {
          return l("allowEmpty") && l("userOptions").deselectable ? f() == t.attr("data-rating-value") : !1
        },
        x = function(n) {
          n.on("click.barrating", function(n) {
            var i, a, r = t(this),
              o = l("userOptions");
            return n.preventDefault(), i = r.attr("data-rating-value"), a = r.attr("data-rating-text"), $(r) && (i = l("emptyRatingValue"), a = l("emptyRatingText")), s("ratingValue", i), s("ratingText", a), s("ratingMade", !0), h(i), v(a), w(), o.onSelect.call(e, f(), c(), n), !1
          })
        },
        C = function(e) {
          e.on("mouseenter.barrating", function() {
            var e = t(this);
            b(), e.addClass("br-active")[p()]().addClass("br-active"), v(e.attr("data-rating-text"))
          })
        },
        O = function(t) {
          e.$widget.on("mouseleave.barrating blur.barrating", function() {
            v(), w()
          })
        },
        R = function(e) {
          e.on("touchstart.barrating", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation(), t(this).click()
          })
        },
        V = function(t) {
          t.on("click.barrating", function(t) {
            t.preventDefault()
          })
        },
        S = function(t) {
          x(t), e.options.hoverState && (C(t), O(t))
        },
        T = function(t) {
          t.off(".barrating")
        },
        j = function(t) {
          var n = e.$widget.find("a");
          l("userOptions").fastClicks && R(n), t ? (T(n), V(n)) : S(n)
        };
      this.show = function() {
        l() || (n(), u(), e.$widget = g(), e.$widget.insertAfter(e.$elem), w(), v(), j(e.options.readonly), e.$elem.hide())
      }, this.readonly = function(t) {
        "boolean" == typeof t && l("readOnly") != t && (j(t), s("readOnly", t), e.$widget.toggleClass("br-readonly"))
      }, this.set = function(t) {
        var n = l("userOptions");
        0 !== e.$elem.find('option[value="' + t + '"]').length && (s("ratingValue", t), s("ratingText", e.$elem.find('option[value="' + t + '"]').text()), s("ratingMade", !0), h(f()), v(c()), w(), n.silent || n.onSelect.call(this, f(), c()))
      }, this.clear = function() {
        var t = l("userOptions");
        s("ratingValue", l("originalRatingValue")), s("ratingText", l("originalRatingText")), s("ratingMade", !1), m(), v(c()), w(), t.onClear.call(this, f(), c())
      }, this.destroy = function() {
        var t = f(),
          n = c(),
          a = l("userOptions");
        T(e.$widget.find("a")), e.$widget.remove(), d(), i(), e.$elem.show(), a.onDestroy.call(this, t, n)
      }
    }
    return e.prototype.init = function(e, n) {
      return this.$elem = t(n), this.options = t.extend({}, t.fn.barrating.defaults, e), this.options
    }, e
  }();
  t.fn.barrating = function(n, i) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var a = new e;
      if (t(this).is("select") || t.error("Sorry, this plugin only works with select fields."), a.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
        if (a.init(i, this), "show" === n) return a.show(i);
        if (a.$elem.data("barrating")) return a.$widget = t(this).next(".br-widget"), a[n](i)
      } else {
        if ("object" == typeof n || !n) return i = n, a.init(i, this), a.show();
        t.error("Method " + n + " does not exist on jQuery.barrating")
      }
    })
  }, t.fn.barrating.defaults = {
    theme: "",
    initialRating: null,
    allowEmpty: null,
    emptyValue: "",
    showValues: !1,
    showSelectedRating: !0,
    deselectable: !0,
    reverse: !1,
    readonly: !1,
    fastClicks: !0,
    hoverState: !0,
    silent: !1,
    triggerChange: !0,
    onSelect: function(t, e, n) {},
    onClear: function(t, e) {},
    onDestroy: function(t, e) {}
  }, t.fn.barrating.BarRating = e
});
//# sourceMappingURL=jquery.barrating.min.js.map
```

```css
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget {
  height: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fbedd9;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
}

.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-active,
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-selected {
  /* background-color: #EDB867; */
  background-image: linear-gradient( #49b4ff, #043063);
}

.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget .br-current-rating {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 2;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  color: #EDB867;
  /* number color */
  font-weight: 400;
}

.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-readonly a {
  cursor: default;
}

.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-readonly a.br-active,
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-readonly a.br-selected {
  /* background-color: #f2cd95; */
  background-image: linear-gradient( #49b4ff, #043063);
}

.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-readonly .br-current-rating {
  /* color: #f2cd95; */
  background-image: linear-gradient( #49b4ff, #043063);
}

@media print {
  .br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a {
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    background: white;
    height: 38px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-active,
  .br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-selected {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
  }
  .br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget .br-current-rating {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/jquery.barrating.js"></script>
<link href="http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/dist/themes/fontawesome-stars.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <script>window.html5 || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/html5shiv.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <section class="">
    <select id="example-1to10" name="rating" autocomplete="off">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7" selected="selected">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

  </section>



  <script src="https://github.com/antennaio/jquery-bar-rating/blob/master/dist/jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script> -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS

```
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a {
   display: block;
   width: 7px;
   margin: 2px 2px;
   padding: 0px 0;
   height: 20px;
   float: left;
   background-color: #fbedd9;
   margin: 3px;
   text-align: center;
   transform: skew(-26deg);
   -webkit-transform: skew(-26deg);
   -moz-transform: skew(-26deg);
}
```

Using `skew` instead of `rotate` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This is the vanilla CSS and HTML code for converting PSD file to code. In case if there is any ambiguity with jQuery plugin

```css
.vertical-line-icon {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 19px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.vertical-line-icon:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient( #49b4ff, #043063);
  /* background-color: #555555; */
  margin-top: 5px;
  -moz-transform: skew(-39deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-39deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-39deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-39deg);
  transform: skew(-39deg);
}

.vertical-line-white-icon {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 19px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.vertical-line-white-icon:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(270deg, #555555, #555555);
  /* background-color: #555555; */
  margin-top: 5px;
  -moz-transform: skew(-39deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-39deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-39deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-39deg);
  transform: skew(-39deg);
}

.blue_white_rechteck img {
  position: relative;
}

.blue_white_rechteck {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row profile_second_row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 blue_white_rechteck" style="">

    <span class="vertical-line-icon "></span>
    <span class="vertical-line-icon "></span>
    <span class="vertical-line-icon "></span>
    <span class="vertical-line-icon "></span>
    <span class="vertical-line-icon "></span>
    <span class="vertical-line-icon "></span>
    <span class="vertical-line-icon "></span>
    <span class="vertical-line-white-icon "></span>
    <span class="vertical-line-white-icon "></span>
    <span class="vertical-line-white-icon "></span>

  </div>
</div>
```